# Multiline env variables parsing differently

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I've got a .env file with public/private multiline keys in it, but only some keys are parsing. While the `PUBLIC_KEY` variable parses correctly with the `dotenv` package, `PRIVATE_KEY` is parsed as `'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.

We've tried swapping their positions in the file, swapping their values, but nothing we do changes the way the file parses--regardless of how we change the file, the `PUBLIC_KEY` alone parses correctly.

```
PUBLIC_KEY='-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAuEdNotdGbDKZO1o7oATA
...
BvnP5uVCRrHigT1b8kvpJ/ptVw3hy2yE9h6V0Lolqq8XJ4kydLrOym5fVCdQlGBV
a9R7j5Z/03IUU34BwHNy648CAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
'
PRIVATE_KEY='-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKQIBAAKCAgEAuEdNotdGbDKZO1o7oATAn6PsIoN3DhVLAZBDjg2JZ54ZDVc/
...
jUId69Z3cNk9QM2q0y26qo8uhEZ+yHCkxC3tBfWJ45YrP+Mj3FsPR044rhmu
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
'
```

We've got a working solution to manually input line breaks into the remaining keys, but we're still curious if anyone knows what could be causing this.

Thank you!

Comment: would that be helpful https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#multi-line-values?

Comment: This absolutely helps, it's the solution we found as well. We just can't figure out why the dotenv package parses the single-quote multi-liners so strangely.